# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input inside a wcm component

Tags: javascript

Anyone know why I'm getting this odd error? I don't see anything wrong with the code.
Its running inside a `Websphere Portal` `WCM` `component`, but that should have no bearing on its execution.

The `alert()` fires correctly.

```
<script>
var AJAX_Utils = {

        updateWishlist: function(param){
            alert('updatewishlist');
            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = '/proxy/https/[Element context="current" type="content" key="sourceUrl"]/store/[Element context="current" type="content" key="storeID"]/wishlist';

            // Error shows up here in Chrome console

            http.open("GET", url, true);
        }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an issue with `Google Chrome Version 36.0.1985.143`

Using `Firefox 32` I was pointed to the correct line with issue.